Using email as a username in registration form
As Grav requires a "username" field to create a user's account I've tried to make it the same as user's email.
I've set Username Regex to **^(.*)^ **, made username field type hidden in the registration form and in the process section I've added the following:
- fill:
        username: "{email}"

but it's not working... Any ideas maybe?

You'll probably have more luck on Discord. See invitation on https://getgrav.org/discord
